# Converting text format to date without the time stamp

Tags: excel, date, text

I would like to convert the text 01.01.2014 00:00:00.000 to date 01/01/2014.
Any help? Is it possible to do it without using a VBA Macro?

thanks vm.

Comment: You could have googled this easily. In future please try to find the answer yourself and include what you've tried in your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's text in a cell then you should be able to use left() and mid().

```
=left(A1, 2)&"/"&mid(A1,4,2)&"/"&mid(A1,7,4)
```

If the text/date is in cell A1.